# Is it best practice to have all angular apps in src directory?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a repo that will have multiple angular apps that are all related under one product.

Is it a best practice to nest all the apps in /src or is it alright to have them in the root of the project? Right now my directory structure is:

```
-project
 --common
 --marketing
 --src 
 --apply
```

Should I actually have:

```
-project
 --src 
  ---common
  ---marketing
  ---apply
```

I'm not really using the src directory for anything at the moment and I can build and run each application separately using this:

`ng serve --app=marketing-app  -sm -ec --port=4002`

`ng serve --app=apply-app  -sm -ec --port=4003`

Or generate things like this:

`ng generate component --app=marketing-app form`

Just curious if i'm doing anything wrong in terms of angular best practices and if i'll run into some unforeseen build issues with angular-cli.

Comment: Why am I getting down votes and closes? Care to share? This is a legitimate Angular architecture question.

Comment: i think the folder structure i project specific. Choose the right for your project.

Comment: You get downvoted for the same reason you get closevoted: it's primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

> Plausible Solution

Source (src), contains things that eventually gets added into the project.

Things which do not go into the build of the project stay out of src.

So you should go with this:

```
-project
 --src 
  ---common
  ---marketing
  ---apply
```